# Точка и текст на Карте Google

Tags: android, google-maps-api, bitmap

Ситуация следующего характера, у меня есть Googleкарта в приложении, мне нужно нарисовать статическую точку (при изменении размера, она имела статичный размер, потому Circle не подходит, если только не получать размер карты и не персчитывать каждый раз (так себе идея)) и второе нужно написать обычный текст, стой же темой, размер статичный, а текст должен быть тупо на карте, без всяких маркеров.

Как вариант, можно использовать: Bitmap, но куда и как его прикрутить я хз, может быть предоставить точку как маркер (но как нарисовать), и как быть с текстом, нее пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для реализации вашей задумки вам нужно проделать следующие шаги:

1. Создать xml - файл , с нужной вам разметкой ( в вашем случае точка и текст)
2. Вам нужно написать метод который создает BitMap

   `private fun getMarkerBitmapFromView(valueOrders: String, isActive: Boolean): Bitmap {
       val customMarkerView = (rootActivity?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater).inflate(R.layout.most_value_marker, null)
       val tv = customMarkerView.findViewById<FontableTextView>(R.id.tv)
       val icon = customMarkerView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.markerIv)
       if (isActive) icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_start_marker) else icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_default)
       tv?.text = "$valueOrders заявок"
       customMarkerView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
       customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.measuredWidth, customMarkerView.measuredHeight)
       customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache()
       val returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.measuredWidth, customMarkerView.measuredHeight,
               Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
       val canvas = Canvas(returnedBitmap)
       canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
       val drawable = customMarkerView.background
       drawable?.draw(canvas)
       customMarkerView.draw(canvas)
       return returnedBitmap
   }`

в этом коде вы можете присвоить какой-либо текст вашему элементу в разметке.

3. Вам нужно создать маркер:

`val marker = map?.addMarker(MarkerOptions()                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(value.toString(), false)))
                        .anchor(0.1f, 0.5f)
                        .position(key))
                marker?.tag = key`

Comment: Отличное решение. Я о таком даже не подумал, это решение так же решит ещё одну мою проблему. Спасибо!